# Correct way of ordering entries by a single month view

Tags: channel-entries, php, entries, grouping

I have a calendar. Currently viewable by year.

I need to add in a drop down/list of some sort which will show

```
January 2015
February 2015
...
```

When the user selects from the list I need to show only entires from that particular month. What is the correct way of achieving this?

I have the following in mind.

I pass variables to the URL either POST or GET so the url looks like

```
domain.com/calendar/january/2016
or
domain.com/calendar?month=january&year=2016
```

Then return the variables, using start_on & stop_before work some magic.

Similar as to above, I could pass some variables into a session & again use the content of the variables to affect my exp loop.

How would you perform this, is my logic sound or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely I can't find this in the documentation, but you can filter entries dynamically by month by simply appending the year and month to the URL.

So given a standard `channel:entries` tag like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="events"}
```

... **/calendar/2015/01** will only show entries with an `entry_date` from January 2015.

On the resulting page, you can use the [Date Heading](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#date-heading) tag pair to dynamically display the month:

```
{date_heading display="monthly"}
    <h1>{entry_date format="%F %Y"}</h1>
{/date_heading}
```

To generate your list of months to filter by, look a the [Archive Month Links](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/archive_month_links.html) tag.